# IOS: Save Array when app is close or enter background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, save

I have a cartArray(in AppDelegate.h @interface above) that need to be saved when the app in background mode or the app closed. The app worked fine when the cartArray has nothing but crashed when I added an item (Cart) in it and entered the background  or closed the application by pressing the minus sign. My cartArray contains cart class in it.
May I know what is happening? The tutorial online is so complicated and I always find myself lost in the middle of explanation.

[AppDelegate.m]

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
[AppDelegate saveData]; 
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {   
[AppDelegate getData];   
}

+(NSString *) getPathToAchieve{  NSLog(@"+++++getPathToAchieve");
    static NSString* docsDir = nil;
    if (docsDir == nil) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        docsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", docsDir];
    return fullFileName;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification{    
    [cartArray writeToFile:[AppDelegate getPathToAchieve] atomically:YES];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{   self = [super init];
   if (self != nil)
   {
        cartArray = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"cartArrayKeys"];
   }
    return self;  
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)anEncoder
{   
    [anEncoder encodeObject:cartArray forKey:@"cartArrayKeys"];
}

+(void)saveData{ 
     [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:cartArray toFile:[self getPathToAchieve] ];
}

+(id)getData{ 
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self getPathToAchieve]];
}
```

Comment: Can you add the crash logs to your question?

Comment: Looks like poor design. I suggest you to use CoreData in this case. You won't have to worry whether data were saved or not - CoreData will take good care of it.

Comment: No need in `CoreData`, there is only one array. `NSDefaults` is preferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty messy. First, implement `-(id)initWithCoder:` and `-(void)encodeWithCoder:` in your `Cart` class, not `AppDelegate` class (and make sure `Cart` conforms to `NSCoding` protocol):

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.title forKey:@"title"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.description forKey:@"description"];
    .....
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.title = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"] ;
        self.description = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"description"] ;
        ....
    }
    return self;
}
```

Second, implement `-(void)saveData` and `-(void)getData`:

```
-(void)saveData{ 
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:cartArray] forKey:@"cartArray"];
}

-(void)getData{ 
    NSData *savedArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"cartArray"];
    if (savedArray != nil)
    {
        NSArray *oldArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedArray];
        if (oldArray != nil) {
            cartArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray];
        } else {
            cartArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
    }
}
```

Call `saveData` when application is going to be terminated / entered background.
Call `getData` when application has loaded.

Comment: Where do I put saveData and loadData? in Cart class too? @Andrey

Comment: I get udeclared currentDefaults for "NSData *savedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"cartArray"];"

Comment: replace currentDefualts by [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]. save your data in applicationWillResignActive: and load it in applicationDidBecomeActive: in your AppDelegate.

Comment: Replaced `currentDefaults`, sorry, that was from my project. See edited answer. `saveData` and `loadData` should belong to `AppDelegate` class, but I'd rather to use another class for that

Answer (score 1):

do all your saving in

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

from the documentation:

> Tells the delegate that the application is about to become inactive.
>   This method is called to let your application know that it is about to
>   move from the active to inactive state. This can occur for certain
>   types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or
>   SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the
>   transition to the background state. An application in the inactive
>   state continues to run but does not dispatch incoming events to
>   responders. You should use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable
>   timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this
>   method to pause the game. An application in the inactive state should
>   do minimal work while it waits to transition to either the active or
>   background state.

Answer (score 0):

Array is a temporary storage if you want to save some data in permanent then try to use NSUSerDefult. After closing app array may vanish.  NSUSerDefult data not vanish. NSUserDefault vanish only when app delete or Remove app from simulator.